# How to use resolvedUrl with getServerSideProps in NextJS 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, getserversideprops

I need to get the pathname without using client-side rendering but I haven't found how to use the getServerSideProps function.

I first tried using usePathname but it turns the component into client-side. I need to keep it server-side

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), `resolvedUrl` is one of the params of `context` object in `getServerSideProps`. You can use that in server-side and then pass it as a prop to the client-side. Here's an example that may help:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { resolvedUrl } = context;

  // You can use the resolvedUrl here, e.g. parse the pathname
  const pathname = new URL(resolvedUrl, "https://example.com").pathname;

  return {
    props: {
      pathname,
    },
  };
}

function MyComponent({ pathname }) {
  return <div>Pathname: {pathname}</div>;
}

export default MyComponent;
```